# nodejs tcp test from remote PC

Tags: node.js, centos

Here is the simple TCP server. Actual IP of the VPS on which this code is running is 1.2.3.4

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write("Echo server\r\n");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Now I am trying to ping this server, while on the same VPS its answering me. But when I am trying to access VPS from some remote PC via command

```
nc 1.2.3.4 1337
```

its not echoing. What could be the possible causes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're listening on `127.0.0.1`, thus it only responds to the requests made from localhost. To respond to other hosts, you need to listen `0.0.0.0`.

**UPDATED**: [RFC5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#page-3) explains this address as follows:

> 0.0.0.0/8 - Addresses in this block refer to source hosts on "this"
> network.  Address 0.0.0.0/32 may be used as a source address for this
> host on this network; other addresses within 0.0.0.0/8 may be used to
> refer to specified hosts on this network

Comment: Whats this 0.0.0.0? I mean the science behind it? as localhost is 127.0.0.1